# Brass push-fitting pipe insertion depth (standard or varies by brand?)

Tags: plumbing, pex, pushfit

I have a 90-degree "elbow" 1/2 (both sides) brass push-fitting installed by previous owner. I'm replacing the PEX pipe. I don't know the brand of the fitting but it is NOT SharkBite. Do all push-fittings have the exact same insertion depth for the same fitting or does it vary slightly? I have a SharkBite depth pipe gauge and marked the insertion depth on it but when I pushed into the non-SharkBite branded fitting I could not get it all the way to the insertion line that I marked. Asking those with far more experience if this is a real possibility before I test it and turn the water back on. (I've tried pushing, twisting, pulling it out and remarking a second time followed by more pushing and twisting only to be about 1/8" short of the marked line that I drew based on a SharkBite insertion tool).

I could test it but want to avoid any leak so thought I'd ask the professionals who've used multiple brands of pipe fittings before I potentially create more work and a mess in my installation.

Answer (score 1):

I would measure the depth to the stop point in the fitting - different fittings different depths.

A small ruler will be sufficient or a vernier caliper will do nicely.

Without the make of the other fitting we cannot say, and even then it might or might not be shown on any drawing we can find.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the fitting and replaced with an actual Sharkbite branded similar fitting. When comparing the size of the Sharkbite with the other it is a bit larger and extends further on both sides of the elbow. I suspect it was just different insertion depths for each elbow as neither leaked when the pipe was in the old or new Sharkbite brand elbow despite different insertion depths. Thanks for the response @SolarMike!